# How to make ImageButton in Android automatically scale based on screen density?

Tags: android, imagebutton, dpi

I have an image put on an `ImageButton`, which looks good on a mdpi (**medium-dpi**) screen. However, when the device has a hdpi (**high-dpi**) screen, the image is still pixel-by-pixel accurate, which look small on the device screen.

How do I make such that the image (and therefore the `ImageButton`) scaled based on the density-independent pixels (**dp** or **dip**) instead of pixels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ponkin mentioned, 9-patches are your best bet. Combined with resource directory qualifiers (`drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, etc.) you can make assets that look good at any density and size.

An example of 9-patches and resource directory qualifiers can be found in the [Multiple Resolutions](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/MultiResolution/index.html) Android SDK sample. The semi-transparent, black, rounded-corner background is implemented as a 9-patch with different PNGs for ldpi, mdpi, and hdpi.

Answer (score 8):

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Other choices include :

```
fitStart
fitCenter
fitEnd
center
cenerCrop
centerInside
matrix
```

Mind you i'm lazy and use really large PNG images in a raw folder.

Comment: I dont think i read the question in full, but this might solve someones qurey :D.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO you should look pretty close to [NinePatchDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html)
. There is, actually, a [tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) that will help you to make your icon(pictures/icons/whatever...) resizable depending on size of container. It`s really simple and works just fine for my needs. Also look at [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)(part "NinePatchDrawable"), it explains the NinePatchDrawable mechanism.

> *A NinePatchDrawable graphic is a stretchable bitmap image, which
>   Android will automatically resize to
>   accomodate the contents of the View in
>   which you have placed it as the
>   background. An example use of a
>   NinePatch is the backgrounds used by
>   standard Android buttons — buttons
>   must stretch to accommodate strings of
>   various lengths. A NinePatch drawable
>   is a standard PNG image that includes
>   an extra 1-pixel-wide border. It must
>   be saved with the extension .9.png,
>   and saved into the res/drawable/
>   directory of your project.*

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should just specify button size in device-independent-pixels?

```
android:layout_width="300dip" 
android:layout_height="50dip"
```

Comment: With this I can't make it automatically resize based on the image size (i.e. when I update the image, I must set the values again)